# Using stringbuilder put time into string (class) C#

Tags: c#, time, stringbuilder

```
   public string getTime()
   {
       StringBuilder RetString = new StringBuilder();
       RetString.Append(Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "-" + Min.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "-" + AMPM.PadLeft(2, '0'));
       return RetString.ToString();
   }
```

I'm attempting to return a time (in string format) back to a form string variable using this. I have the user setup to enter a time and the time is stored in this class, and all im doing now is bringing that data to the form im working in. I've verified that the data is going into the class and being stored in the variables.

The error i get is :

[image: CSharp_Null]

Not really sure what the problem is. 
I have the variables declared of course

```
    private int Hours;
    private int Min;
    private string AMPM;
```

I have get sets setup:

```
public int _hours
    {
        get
        {
            return Hours;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 12 && value >= 1)
            {
                Hours = value;
            }
            else
                Hours = 0;
        }
    }

    public int _min
    {
        get
        {
            return Min;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 59 && value >= 1)
            {
                Min = value;
            }
            else
                Min = 0;
        }
    }

    public string ampm
    {
        get
        {
            return AMPM;
        }
        set
        {
            if (AMPM == "AM" || AMPM == "PM")
            {
                AMPM = value;
            }
            else
                AMPM = "";
        }
    }
```

and my call to the class:

```
string timefromclass;
timefromclass = timec.getTime();
```

The only thing that I think it could be would be my call to the class where i store the time is

```
C_Time time = new C_Time();
```

but in the other form i setup another one as well.

```
C_Time timec = new C_Time();
```

Possibly i'm trying to retrieve the time from an empty instance?

EDIT:

```
public void setTime(int hours, int min, string aMPM)
    {
        Hours = hours;
        Min = min;
        AMPM = aMPM;
```

That's really the only place I assigned that variable anything.

Comment: When looking at the null reference exception in visual studio, you should be able to isolate the actual object that is null. That would point you in the right direction. As others have said likely AMPM.

Comment: just a side note - your casing is somewhat off, based on standard c# conventions. Public methods and properties should be `PascalCase`, while private members should be `camelCase`. Use of underscore prefixes usually applies to private variables but you're using them for public properties.

Comment: Well it seems that AMPM is in fact null and empty. But now my problem is, the numbers i passed to this class for the time they entered isn't showing up in this instance.

Comment: Your setter code for ampm is wrong. Should be `if(value == "AM" || value == "PM")` The current if condition you have will never be met based on your class design.

Comment: Alright i changed that over to what you suggested, the error still occurs however. >_< I'm not sure what i'm missing here. when i view all of the values on the variables when i first assign them they end up right but when i go to retrieve the values they are 0 or like that string is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you code, I assume your `AMPM` field is `null`.

You do not seem to instantiate it anywhere apart from the setter, which you are **not** calling in your code.

Initializing it should solve the issue:

```
private string AMPM = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thank you! this fixed the issue. :D Now the values just aren't being showing up like they should be.

Answer (score 4):

Do you initialize `AMPM` somewhere in the code. If not it will be null (the default value for a reference type variable) and calling `PadLeft` on it will give you a NRE.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting means that you are trying to read a "reference type" that hasn't been initialized and is therefore **null**.

**int** is a "value type" and value types can't represent null values.

**string** is a "reference type" and is the only reference type you have in your class (`AMPM`).  This must be where the problem is.

You will need to initialize `AMPM` to stop the error.  If you don't already have one, adding a **constructor** to your class is a nice way to handle initializations.  For example:

```
public C_Time()
{
    AMPM = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed out `AMPM` is the problem. You should define it like this

```
private string _ampm;

public string AMPM
{
    get
    {
        return _ampm ?? ""; // Returns "" if _ampm == null
    }
    set
    {
        _ampm = value;
    }
}
```

Then work with the property

```
AMPM.PadLeft( ...
```

---

But why not just use

```
String.Format("{0:00}-{1:00}-{2}", Hours, Min, AMPM.PadLeft(2, '0'));
```

---

It would be safer to work with an enum

```
public enum AmPm
{
    Undefined,
    AM,
    PM
}
```

This clearly enumerates the valid entries. Otherwise you could enter something like "afternoon" or "am" instead of "AM".